# Flutter login with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart, authentication

does anybody how to use wordpress as backend in a flutter app. I am always getting this error when I try to login :

Failed to fetch user: WordPress Error! code: null, message: {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}, status: null

Any documentation or help concerning this topic is very much appreciated

Comment: Have you check the url on POSTMAN is its working?

Comment: Like the error says, the url is not found (404).

Comment: @ArbiterChil I am using the same url to get data from the post section and it is working . It's only the user section that is not working